# check if a specific user has permission to a document library

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to check if a specific user has permission to a document library and then ill display the library that they have permission to.

I get the user as a string so need to use that to check:

```
// Get the current user.
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.Users[userName]; //not sure about this it crashes

// Get the list.
SPList spList = spWeb.Lists[docLibrary]; //passed from autostore

bool userPermission = spList.DoesUserHavePermissions(user, SPBasePermissions.AddListItems);

if (userPermission)
{
    // Perform operation here.
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: the user name string I get is something like "iainl"

Comment: Error at runtime - system.argumentException

Comment: SPList spList = spWeb.Lists[docLibrary]; //passed from autostore
                        SPUser user = spWeb.EnsureUser("<iainl>");
                        bool userPermission = spList.DoesUserHavePermissions(user, SPBasePermissions.AddListItems);

                        if (userPermission)

                        {

Comment: Essentially I need to take a string userName and check if the user has access to a library name? THANKS

Comment: Fixed! I was being stupid